# A Relation between quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, density-operator

The following is from 'Discerning Fermions' by Muller & Saunders (2008: 532):

> Let $|\phi_{1}\rangle, |\phi_{2}\rangle, ..., |\phi_{d}\rangle$ $\in$
>   $\scr{H}$ be an eigenbasis of $\scr{H}$ belonging to operator A acting
>   in $\scr{H}$. Let $P_{m}$ be the 1-dimensional projector on the ray to
>   which eigenstate $|\phi_{m}\rangle$ of A belongs.

1. Now, what would be the braket representation of this projector? Is it just $|\phi_{m}\rangle\langle\phi_{m}|$?

The textbook continues to define a relation as follows, using the above projector:

> Let $P_{lm} \equiv P_{l} - P_{m}$.
>
> The consider the following family of relations between particles $a$
>   and $b$:
>
> $$R_t(a,b) \leftrightarrow\sum_{l,m=1}^{d}P_{lm}^{(a)}P_{lm}^{(b)}W =
>  tW$$ where each relation is characterized by a value of parameter $t \in R$.

2. Any idea as to what the physical significance of these relations are? 
   $W$ is just a state.

Any partial answer to either of the above two questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the context here, what is $W$?

Comment: Also, please cite the relevant details of the textbook.

Comment: I've added the information to the main text.

Comment: The paper is [here](https://www.academia.edu/207929/Discerning_Fermions) (scroll down to read it - you don't need to download).